# What's the difference between inheriting an angular component from an Abstract Class versus an Abstract Component?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to re-use certain business logic and properties that are used across various view components. I created an abstract class with the required properties and functions and inherited this in my component. It worked great. I also created an abstract component with an empty template and then moved my business logic here. Inheriting this abstract component too works without any issues? Which approach is right?

Approach 1:

```
export abstract class GridViewBase implements IFilterView {
// Bla bla
}
```

Then in my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'order-view',
  templateUrl: './order-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-view.component.css']
})
export class OrderViewComponent extends GridViewBase implements AfterContentChecked, OnInit {
 }
```

---

Approach 2:

Abstract Component:

```
@Component({
    template: ''
})
export abstract class BaseComponent {
```

View Component:

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'order-view',
      templateUrl: './order-view.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./order-view.component.css']
    })
    export class OrderViewComponent extends BaseComponent implements AfterContentChecked, OnInit {
}
```

Both works! Which is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are perfectly valid reasons for using either.

I would use an Abstract component or component inheritance when:

1. I have the same component logic (same models, data and behavior) but different views (template swapping).
2. I don't want to inject dependencies on the base class using super keyword as angular will handle injection
3. My base class contains angular annotations such as @Input or @Output, which indicates that the base class will always require component views to work properly.
4. I need to write common code that would be executed during any of the angular component life cycle hooks for example ngAfterContentChecked() or ngOnDestroy(). The component inheriting this base abstract component doesn't have to worry about handing these hooks separately inside itself.

I would use an Abstract or class inhecritance when:

1. I want to use the same class as a base for non-component classes as well as components.
2. There is no component logic at all (no html template dependency or any other dependency) just a need for some generic ( like parameter) and functions the the T type.